# How to create an expirable link?

Tags: php, laravel, date, routes, hyperlink

I'm trying to do a website with Laravel where you can upload a file. This file can be accessed with the name and a token through a link. But I want it to be expirable. Therefore, I added a column in the database called `expires_at`.

How can I check if the date has expired or is still valid? Currently, I'm doing this:

```php
Route::get('/documents/{document}/{token}', function ($documentId, $token) {
    $document = upload::where('id', $documentId)
        ->where('token', $token)
        ->firstOrFail();

    if ($document->expires_at <= now()) {
        abort(404);
    }

    return response()->file(public_path('storage/' . $document->path));
});
```

Comment: Ok. In what way does this code not do the thing you said you want?

Comment: Super quick tip: instead of doing `upload::where('id', xxx)->where('token', yyy)->firstOrFail();`, you can do `Upload::where('token', yyy)->findOrFail($documentId);`: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions

Comment: @matiaslauriti - you could even combine the expiration logic. `$document = Upload::where('token', $token)->where('expires_at', '<=', now())->findOrFail($documentId);